# Remove some part of data

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Consider the following dataset:

```
    dataset={{0.001000000159197672, 9.99999999999992*^-7}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  1.1242100306002744*^-6}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  1.4208308156167856*^-6}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  1.7957144587371621*^-6}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  2.269510473643477*^-6}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  2.86831671088713*^-6}, 
   {0.001000000159197672, 
  3.6251168917261416*^-6}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  4.581597432667653*^-6}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  5.790443635882787*^-6}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  7.31824172531303*^-6}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  9.249146579759014*^-6}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.00001168951719071683}, 
   {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.000014773775177387728}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.0000186718090602862}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.00002359833213905933}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.000029824709429458177}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.00003769390511625662}, 
   {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.00004763937386461134}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.00006020893656978565}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.00007609495568029223}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.00009617247222551723}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.0001215474052291657}, 
   {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.00015361746845084348}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.0001941491598998232}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.0002453750648928894}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.00031011683234816054}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.00039194059815180534}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.000495353416699202}, 
   {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.0006260515205432618}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.0007912340829023327}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.0011725698740214546, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.0013749198905786443, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.0016121893862285957, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, 
   {0.0018904044045608105, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.002216630901622993, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.002599154203288838, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.0030476894315276644, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.003573628243869615, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.00419032815262322, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, 
   {0.00491345177181988, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.005761364607897496, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.006755601496998003, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.007921413535203503, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.009288409392352266, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.01089130729717943, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, 
   {0.012770816792298337, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.01497467265336332, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.017558847231339155, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.02058897200829692, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.024142004470649077, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.02830818263417762, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, 
   {0.03319331686083523, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.03594346845418379, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.0374028459743575, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.03878858291629611, 
  0.0009999997658388317}, {0.03883685551836095, 
  0.0009968034631843803}, {0.03892147717365525, 
  0.0009931630537797064}, 
   {0.040163171163316934, 0.000931565406537484}, {0.0405017678712987, 
  0.0009130066614999238}, {0.040932212450600684, 
  0.000889513292551626}, {0.04140583701262171, 
  0.0008666244519247692}, {0.04214622156763605, 
  0.0008351554384906082}, {0.04278661347830955, 
  0.0008089807656135544}, 
   {0.04327496689203805, 
  0.0007912340829023327}, {0.04430977192007963, 
  0.0007575927561034032}, {0.045638144320755546, 
  0.0007077271117283544}, {0.04570204582215624, 
  0.0007052633789414318}, {0.04572336619942735, 
  0.0007038133990672945}, {0.04593711777559279, 
  0.0006970861438207811}, 
   {0.047174723069779746, 
  0.0006572996648502417}, {0.04832907060081713, 
  0.0006260515205432618}, {0.04879336998419748, 
  0.0006144216875893396}, {0.04941938184659282, 
  0.0005999818977648285}, {0.05048324995767317, 
  0.0005746035247144968}, {0.051138892499691245, 
  0.000556881279745365}, 
   {0.05207759871076419, 
  0.0005350361388009571}, {0.05351390461747229, 
  0.0005059428593318458}, {0.053848772643597755, 
  0.0004999194505152742}, {0.05408263954857633, 
  0.000495353416699202}, {0.05568667738465831, 
  0.00046954399048999943}, {0.05577331882207561, 
  0.00046825729210363254}, 
   {0.056357303997745634, 
  0.00045903357716356154}, {0.057311553096389474, 
  0.00044062355184173454}, {0.05756157756621795, 
  0.00043631215824534565}, {0.057947669120943485, 
  0.00042967832747416244}, {0.05942564773050986, 
  0.00040673233871704994}, {0.06056352542553819, 
  0.00039194059815180534}, 
   {0.06152200610144253, 
  0.00038072175920003546}, {0.06274878240624557, 
  0.00036700181567461134}, {0.06362304126796989, 
  0.000355804562770912}, {0.06417936942616617, 
  0.00034863645358378857}, {0.06562726584466179, 
  0.00033126586670897653}, {0.06720178989583887, 
  0.0003151929183331249}, 
   {0.06773673667486248, 
  0.00031011683234816054}, {0.06782630756450275, 
  0.00030930237711136364}, {0.06794768026386919, 
  0.0003082785033652491}, {0.07024631304242215, 
  0.0002896880170334542}, {0.07181433160682603, 
  0.00027585310921178177}, {0.07246481366792332, 
  0.00026974000580225617}, 
   {0.073577320167753, 0.0002607637811375262}, {0.07482604896722068, 
  0.0002515248452955868}, {0.07572422506655, 
  0.0002453750648928894}, {0.07740248562612552, 
  0.0002351573189549188}, {0.07967339020323692, 
  0.00022259927994789687}, {0.08007230312513398, 
  0.0002198737338042365}, 
   {0.08029513056095959, 
  0.00021826443299199956}, {0.08127632718915224, 
  0.00021196233429267427}, {0.08255137897194964, 
  0.00020455182152397843}, {0.08460096802160764, 
  0.0001941491598998232}, {0.08531585673903667, 
  0.00019098422914224438}, {0.08627453530523323, 
  0.0001867465431247532}, 
   {0.0883100971580823, 
  0.00017872478172960954}, {0.08977745594152022, 
  0.00017270817205111615}, {0.08977920063137373, 
  0.00017269829890786086}, {0.09109908347349162, 
  0.00016641773503245868}, {0.09342260224081098, 
  0.00015724265583259698}, {0.09401999146400457, 
  0.0001550644963073943}, 
   {0.09441547872083596, 
  0.00015361746845084348}, {0.09724598112909881, 
  0.000144949091869821}, {0.09758674276139297, 
  0.0001440733802412438}, {0.09898100531780703, 
  1.608461293224791*^-8}, {0.09410773411186633, 
  1.6608830133395988*^-8}, {0.09364071768218774, 
  1.6665897825205658*^-8}, 
   {0.09342260224081098, 
  1.6692596477992305*^-8}, {0.09281457806549673, 
  1.6769114254151746*^-8}, {0.08865399648864196, 
  1.728695672873001*^-8}, {0.08627453530523323, 
  1.762524607941122*^-8}, {0.08402422790271839, 
  1.795988514289155*^-8}, {0.07969816713478378, 
  1.866327590445377*^-8}, 
   {0.07967339020323692, 
  1.866754418040126*^-8}, {0.07966100462615044, 
  1.866754418040126*^-8}, {0.07964862097445614, 
  1.8671813432500016*^-8}, {0.0755654619389593, 
  1.941862212843724*^-8}, {0.073577320167753, 
  1.982467589049245*^-8}, {0.07176410793768351, 
  2.0234592818782815*^-8}, 
   {0.06835028457120025, 
  2.0991039950313628*^-8}, {0.06809573151829212, 
  2.105834882231386*^-8}, {0.06794768026386919, 
  2.108243997488058*^-8}, {0.06754744742037765, 
  2.1174237977085206*^-8}, {0.06459980562251452, 
  2.190812418118467*^-8}, {0.06274878240624557, 
  2.2377745470273994*^-8}, 
   {0.061278591400413085, 
  2.2789585009470597*^-8}, {0.05866376219027568, 
  2.3598337664873862*^-8}, {0.058198206666981445, 
  2.3748561217887796*^-8}, {0.057947669120943485, 
  2.383152328661523*^-8}, {0.05710698849053854, 
  2.411108123067329*^-8}, {0.055289857111338866, 
  2.47592116833625*^-8}, 
   {0.05455554519173364, 
  2.5021027431687974*^-8}, {0.05351390461747229, 
  2.540151934402316*^-8}, {0.052508476383064745, 
  2.579959399865051*^-8}, {0.05066211837360102, 
  2.652948790834367*^-8}, {0.04986701424311396, 
  2.688369318892662*^-8}, {0.04941938184659282, 
  2.7081137132520885*^-8}, 
   {0.048010797372564945, 
  2.7682212256948292*^-8}, {0.04731335727174096, 
  2.7974137583808794*^-8}, {0.045638144320755546, 
  2.8723647703932014*^-8}, {0.04487128334754098, 
  2.9090512752037433*^-8}, {0.04347051374556906, 
  2.982471641324889*^-8}, {0.04261732623642878, 
  3.031636244943236*^-8}, 
   {0.04214622156763605, 
  3.061243152930387*^-8}, {0.040539565496046086, 
  3.166619774538652*^-8}, {0.04040428703974425, 
  3.1735063973303665*^-8}, {0.03892147717365525, 
  3.260677025280723*^-8}, {0.03842844578592374, 
  3.290639002783678*^-8}, {0.037566017729956006, 
  3.3529245351583316*^-8}, 
   {0.036527924711018143, 
  3.433423223961261*^-8}, {0.03594346845418379, 
  3.479463072101872*^-8}, {0.034686326638383606, 
  3.577082161875432*^-8}, {0.03408228863136359, 
  3.625670144168904*^-8}, {0.03319331686083523, 
  3.702754706137342*^-8}, {0.03293629474062846, 
  3.7265389326338704*^-8}, 
   {0.03241308463392539, 
  3.7693913942707895*^-8}, {0.03127941985907712, 
  3.883128134758993*^-8}, {0.030653588304318476, 
  3.9593436124581344*^-8}, {0.030348922337943656, 
  3.9966393741879754*^-8}, {0.029803036966040152, 
  4.0657748066191924*^-8}, {0.029457552106574282, 
  4.1097079262982246*^-8}, 
   {0.028361043602601627, 
  4.23758761469761*^-8}, {0.028325241542169883, 
  4.241344239172365*^-8}, {0.02830818263417762, 
  4.243405737256695*^-8}, {0.02824663601655595, 
  4.251175661932172*^-8}, {0.026909216160095704, 
  4.421713687529609*^-8}, {0.026142231574796115, 
  4.541612286378918*^-8}, 
   {0.025610721405671368, 
  4.6221562534675864*^-8}, {0.024686651794561625, 
  4.763938501990583*^-8}, {0.024142004470649077, 
  4.860219653480206*^-8}, {0.023250586657332102, 
  5.035000457356838*^-8}, {0.023192823546745477, 
  5.048835857409506*^-8}, {0.02316759733252072, 
  5.0511454507496145*^-8}, 
   {0.022294821243292635, 
  5.220093807012738*^-8}, {0.022053509894113258, 
  5.270621166584722*^-8}, {0.021635800940687212, 
  5.355667449100702*^-8}, {0.02142492591604778, 
  5.402408711612823*^-8}, {0.020975054169910915, 
  5.504036676318751*^-8}, {0.02058897200829692, 
  5.6005282007359924*^-8}, 
   {0.01997726945417705, 
  5.7596307206536064*^-8}, {0.019098075292201963, 
  5.98178338827889*^-8}, {0.019013642842548712, 
  6.007142633394138*^-8}, {0.018995915209594347, 
  6.012639833287079*^-8}, {0.018960509514086475, 
  6.020895066838443*^-8}, {0.01809931148806184, 
  6.295450138930537*^-8}, 
   {0.017558847231339155, 
  6.470594154548422*^-8}, {0.01722894865831908, 
  6.582525025232106*^-8}, {0.01672227177916228, 
  6.768750627331543*^-8}, {0.016406815522017233, 
  6.886626473275197*^-8}, {0.016215362760657517, 
  6.960244720586633*^-8}, {0.01562634222125135, 7.20642461700869*^-8}, 
   {0.015411617054220656, 
  7.294295519074413*^-8}, {0.01497467265336332, 
  7.498514062564036*^-8}, {0.014886467201858053, 
  7.543660510756418*^-8}, {0.014748252057700069, 
  7.609497349878083*^-8}, {0.014172807410262838, 
  7.889458158010977*^-8}, {0.013854735042451514, 
  8.068256528766564*^-8}, 
   {0.013828911778615954, 
  8.082105846806865*^-8}, {0.013518557267589928, 
  8.273779759322756*^-8}, {0.013289337784914675, 
  8.388081517899114*^-8}, {0.012970911530143748, 
  8.554673248559217*^-8}, {0.012840496373493271, 
  8.623415782340407*^-8}, {0.012770816792298337, 
  8.66096420377274*^-8}, 
   {0.012460939717114641, 
  8.869407997237177*^-8}, {0.012241086256892538, 
  9.036255774038685*^-8}, {0.011793680092358805, 
  9.352654400418512*^-8}, {0.011651529031853881, 
  9.447232199359377*^-8}, {0.011425510801527448, 
  9.617249474538185*^-8}, {0.011106757971027713, 
  9.898380014110327*^-8}, 
   {0.01089130729717943, 
  1.0083431433030765*^-7}, {0.010574298088409434, 
  1.0352116832678776*^-7}, {0.010107747492655665, 
  1.0811808326061134*^-7}, {0.010079893313605525, 
  1.0846476957269136*^-7}, {0.01005797797741257, 
  1.0870686829807311*^-7}, {0.009942928850089827, 
  1.09963203694263*^-7}, 
   {0.009587527599536, 
  1.1327796986511408*^-7}, {0.009288409392352266, 
  1.1610707341707153*^-7}, {0.009108231336093077, 
  1.1809528338258234*^-7}, {0.008799236823442398, 
  1.2154743369085588*^-7}, {0.008655418564114148, 
  1.2317025969501208*^-7}, {0.008577723000953722, 
  1.2410324418107782*^-7}, 
   {0.008260999711052706, 
  1.284633258738106*^-7}, {0.008240476313217709, 
  1.2881632316161888*^-7}, {0.008231513367400781, 
  1.2887525027481365*^-7}, {0.007921413535203503, 
  1.3325054424914558*^-7}, {0.007836893204360406, 
  1.3450572213596716*^-7}, {0.0076977260835879, 
  1.3664484414898304*^-7}, 
   {0.00745278619120872, 
  1.4043837455360468*^-7}, {0.0073153204397867, 
  1.42712634291339*^-7}, {0.0070910872662655776, 
  1.4674171492133944*^-7}, {0.006766112359771801, 
  1.5326662394967894*^-7}, {0.006755601496998003, 
  1.5345950891256965*^-7}, {0.00675350128463596, 
  1.5354726412341908*^-7}, 
   {0.006751401725197557, 
  1.536175044220992*^-7}, {0.00642673914816256, 
  1.6047566722617484*^-7}, {0.0063226808317385875, 
  1.6287875216965364*^-7}, {0.00623870846969656, 
  1.6475173823125*^-7}, {0.006111747541905601, 
  1.6755377765911996*^-7}, {0.005995287664182604, 
  1.70150377912478*^-7}, 
   {0.005888137077944084, 
  1.7269833934710734*^-7}, {0.0058063240715672, 
  1.746842434515362*^-7}, {0.005761364607897496, 
  1.7584651471148278*^-7}, {0.005572838534950285, 
  1.8135970848175362*^-7}, {0.005531406622926399, 
  1.8285886541663414*^-7}, {0.005320543876407216, 
  1.9002045000253096*^-7}, 
   {0.005273603697098033, 
  1.9163501517216245*^-7}, {0.005199520940654055, 
  1.9414920536202972*^-7}, {0.005020005727928008, 
  2.0037364370195552*^-7}, {0.00491345177181988, 
  2.0407298203067434*^-7}, {0.004776374604155558, 
  2.093670778754236*^-7}, 
   {0.004591438285900026, 
  2.1826448410106817*^-7}, {0.00455871994318126, 
  2.1976696793275459*^-7}, {0.004537507607267811, 
  2.2064818862416246*^-7}, {0.004456584357261374, 
  2.241188431761521*^-7}, {0.004335453435621767, 
  2.294733617442245*^-7}, {0.00419032815262322, 
  2.3688445812841892*^-7}, 
   {0.004129536618358079, 
  2.401570023501788*^-7}, {0.004026517675686913, 
  2.4537512235021697*^-7}, {0.003927289665241572, 
  2.5076395781450546*^-7}, {0.003869712526441252, 
  2.544899892695267*^-7}, {0.003747744270313401, 
  2.631599704602951*^-7}, {0.003596479748209916, 
  2.732789725133873*^-7}, 
   {0.003573628243869615, 
  2.749714633677491*^-7}, {0.003568631526411495, 
  2.752860359646503*^-7}, {0.0035597657175378953, 
  2.758531738058857*^-7}, {0.003395438554883098, 
  2.876417869385932*^-7}, {0.003300198332077965, 
  2.96117811241076*^-7}, {0.003240207999396863, 
  3.018607810054582*^-7}, 
   {0.003149811562059678, 
  3.1011690496550016*^-7}, {0.0030476894315276644, 
  3.1947430043116504*^-7}, {0.0029406376759994776, 
  3.3077392470400665*^-7}, {0.002879115174751381, 
  3.3718902226419505*^-7}, {0.0028145008076520613, 
  3.446730482310965*^-7}, 
   {0.0028014045575413507, 
  3.462530070582042*^-7}, {0.002781441899066985, 
  3.486365352209302*^-7}, {0.002667519420005385, 
  3.6220789045982484*^-7}, {0.002599154203288838, 
  3.7084035226288293*^-7}, {0.002539835503311201, 
  3.788546345192307*^-7}, 
   {0.0024561529746961975, 
  3.9194068992909875*^-7}, {0.002423532481536643, 
  3.975370969178294*^-7}, {0.0024002844675357383, 
  4.0096073072158193*^-7}, {0.0023087832256718467, 
  4.161404661753855*^-7}, {0.0022982187883894526, 
  4.178091045188788*^-7}, 
   {0.002216630901622993, 
  4.3214185964050315*^-7}, {0.00219844151908839, 
  4.3531567182322537*^-7}, {0.0021722810521136765, 
  4.406236550186884*^-7}, {0.0020982607160390044, 
  4.5693910552223647*^-7}, {0.0020470292669411715, 
  4.6665398563952445*^-7}, 
   {0.001993636396191247, 
  4.764664441636167*^-7}, {0.0019224129743674282, 
  4.953535326917685*^-7}, {0.0018904044045608105, 
  5.038071317335496*^-7}, {0.001821735757518771, 
  5.230598520900636*^-7}, {0.0018160801784405645, 
  5.249771122997625*^-7}, {0.001745763419456578, 
  5.45662366968651*^-7}, 
   {0.0017314379137406007, 
  5.501729251758299*^-7}, {0.0017108345799844405, 
  5.568814101453716*^-7}, {0.0016504839662849118, 
  5.764461560746182*^-7}, {0.0016121893862285957, 
  5.891058481385677*^-7}, {0.0015723369604614622, 
  6.034218541458125*^-7}, 
   {0.0015121627958422617, 
  6.260516671402574*^-7}, {0.0014978900539082353, 
  6.316599221344072*^-7}, {0.001488835536419478, 
  6.357173182756996*^-7}, {0.0014383271562502203, 
  6.586539724501689*^-7}, {0.00142941044475993, 
  6.628847618237231*^-7}, {0.0014267462261421606, 
  6.637948892682775*^-7}, 
   {0.0013749198905786443, 
  6.877445810262808*^-7}, {0.0013619425333574885, 
  6.940641850547448*^-7}, {0.00134260143284372, 
  7.038135638731073*^-7}, {0.0012982644635820058, 
  7.272088705855604*^-7}, {0.001269720301044837, 
  7.425000865626267*^-7}, {0.001237371298152167, 
  7.617621494965937*^-7}, 
   {0.0011953937805494498, 
  7.912342681786806*^-7}, {0.0011725698740214546, 
  8.056579403456906*^-7}, {0.0011363184296544159, 
  8.286402000670257*^-7}, {0.0011245436804970526, 
  8.364457280753112*^-7}, {0.0011210525343823116, 
  8.389359712594886*^-7}, 
   {0.0010828527419237807, 
  8.676160899834713*^-7}, {0.0010719652719384063, 
  8.763897724700829*^-7}, {0.001056085223862391, 
  8.895135008411475*^-7}, {0.0010406021883080092, 
  9.024209408597328*^-7}, {0.0010223218832301035, 
  9.188714717973889*^-7}, 
   {0.001000000159197672, 
  9.413626276187565*^-7}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  9.431402339213084*^-7}, {0.001000000159197672, 
  9.99999999999992*^-7}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.0000590904665211349}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.0000545703876121958}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.000053556661950113064}, 
   {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.00005256176774155176}, {0.03472949396023496, 
  0.00005010878500406351}, {0.034353594061670746, 
  0.00005010878500406351}, {0.03319331686083523, 
  0.00005010878500406351}, {0.032072227501026236, 
  0.00005010878500406351}, 
   {0.031725088925434894, 
  0.00005010878500406351}, {0.030653588304318476, 
  0.00005010878500406351}, {0.02961827713514504, 
  0.00005010878500406351}, {0.029297699260227062, 
  0.00005010878500406351}, {0.02830818263417762, 
  0.00005010878500406351}, 
   {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.00005319051038777381}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.000053556661950113064}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.000053925334017813635}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.0000597973053106839}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.00006020893656978565}, 
   {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.000060623401406296784}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.00006722473043313845}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.00006768749042352927}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.00006815343595006619}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.00007557471625733439}, 
   {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.00007609495568029223}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.00007661877631493838}, {0.02830818263417762, 
  0.00007943311442865322}, {0.029146642603868587, 
  0.00007943311442865322}, {0.029771778105117472, 
  0.00007943311442865322}, 
   {0.030653588304318476, 
  0.00007943311442865322}, {0.03156151683695155, 
  0.00007943311442865322}, {0.032238446420787215, 
  0.00007943311442865322}, {0.03319331686083523, 
  0.00007943311442865322}, {0.03417646960535215, 
  0.00007943311442865322}, {0.03454103266373427, 
  0.00007943311442865322}, 
   {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.00007609495568029223}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.00007468137933048964}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.00006896868576965121}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.00006768749042352927}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.0000664300951759101}, 
   {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.00006134857712737598}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.00006020893656978565}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.0000590904665211349}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.00024081686014116894}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.0002223957632278165}, 
   {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.00021826443299199956}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.00021420984832574592}, {0.03529009541010933, 
  0.00019945928838200572}, {0.03380786942093058, 
  0.00019945928838200572}, {0.03319331686083523, 
  0.00019945928838200572}, {0.032589935511927945, 
  0.00019945928838200572}, 
   {0.03122111945064857, 
  0.00019945928838200572}, {0.030653588304318476, 
  0.00019945928838200572}, {0.030096373623500258, 
  0.00019945928838200572}, {0.028832290127936634, 
  0.00019945928838200572}, {0.02830818263417762, 
  0.00019945928838200572}, 
   {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.00021677222156146728}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.00021826443299199956}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.0002197669164718626}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.0002436975058349086}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.0002453750648928894}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.0002470641718917626}, 
   {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.00027396718049187537}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.00027585310921178177}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.0002777520202426722}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.00030799665236424465}, {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.00031011683234816054}, 
   {0.028176460859947176, 
  0.0003122516071763051}, {0.02830818263417762, 
  0.0003162759164840821}, {0.02868920780508525, 
  0.0003162759164840821}, {0.030246473935670266, 
  0.0003162759164840821}, {0.030653588304318476, 
  0.0003162759164840821}, {0.031066182389693744, 
  0.0003162759164840821}, 
   {0.03275247202064942, 
  0.0003162759164840821}, {0.03319331686083523, 
  0.0003162759164840821}, {0.03364009542635926, 
  0.0003162759164840821}, {0.03454103266373427, 
  0.0003162759164840821}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.00031011683234816054}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.00030435595350982}, 
   {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.00028107448346460155}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.00027585310921178177}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.00027072872970836776}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.000250019547783717}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.0002453750648928894}, {0.035488160500357094, 
  0.00024081686014116894}};
```

It includes wrong points - two rectangles inside the domain:

```
ListLogLogPlot[dataset]
```

[image]

These points belong to the region

```
0.026 < #[[1]] < 0.038 && 10^-5 < #[[2]] < 3.7*10^-4
```

Could you please tell me how to remove the mentioned points quickly? I was thinking of `Select`, but I do not know the option "Not belonging to the given region" in Mathematica language and hence cannot just directly use the region above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there.

**Using `DeleteCases`:**

```
d2 = DeleteCases[
   dataset, _?(0.026 < #[[1]] < 0.038 && 
       10^-5 < #[[2]] < 3.7*10^-4 &)];

ListLogLogPlot[d2]
```

---

**Using `IntervalMemberQ`:**

```
Clear[intervalx, intervaly];
intervalx = Interval[{0.026, 0.038}];
intervaly = Interval[{10^-5, 3.7*10^-4}];
d3 = Select[
   dataset, ! IntervalMemberQ[intervalx, First@#] || ! 
      IntervalMemberQ[intervaly, Last@#] &];

d3==d2
```

> True

---

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'd just create a helper function to use as a predicate, and you basically already defined it:

```
BadPoints[{x_, y_}] := 0.026 < x < 0.038 && 10^-5 < y < 3.7*10^-4
```

Now,

```
ListLogLogPlot[Select[dataset, Not@*BadPoints]]
```